# String type check variable not saving actual string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2005

here are 2 screen shots when i try to debug my code in visual studio 2005

[image: string saved in string type variable a][image]

i want to save string value in variable `check` in variable `a` but it saves `-1` not the actual string which is something like that `"<username>admin</username>"`

Comment: What is the type of `a`?

Comment: By the way, line 1 is absolutely redundant. You should've written `string check = a.ToString ()` instead.

Comment: ... and how is ToString() for a.GetType() implemented?

Comment: @gaearon ...a is of String type

Comment: @Albin   a.GetType() gives me this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'string'
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the value of `check` in `a`, then your assignment is the wrong way round. Currently it's converting the value of `a` to a string, and storing the result in `check`.

Of course, you haven't specified the type of `a` - it may be converted to a string one way in the debugger, but the actual `ToString` method may be overridden to do something different.

If you actually meant to describe the question the other way round, you need to provide a *lot* more information - a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem would be ideal.

String assignment very definitely works in C# - so the chances are incredibly high that you're doing something strange in the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: +1. This is the easiest way to get debugger to show different value instead of result of ToString - DebuggerDisplayAttribute - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx